# How could I have chosen to use the selected name in placeholders?

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<fieldset>

<?php $q3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tz_kliendid"); 
echo "<select name='nimetus' id='nimetus'><option value=''>--- Valige klient ---</option>";
while($f3=mysql_fetch_assoc($q3)){ $klient=$f3['klient']; if($f3['id']==$klient){ $selected = "selected"; $selectedval = $f3['teenus'];} echo '<option value="'.$f3['id'].'" $selected>'.$f3['vnimi'].'-'.$f3['teenus'].'</option>';}echo '</select>'; ?><br />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="EDASI" /><input type="submit" name="register" class="next action-button" value="LISA" /></fieldset>

<fieldset><div class="log"><div class="content2"><div style="text-align:center"><input type="text" name="kogus" placeholder="<?php echo $selectedval; ?>"></div><br />
<input name="to" type="text" class="tcal" placeholder=""></div></div><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="KINNITA" /></fieldset></form>
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` in 2016. `mysqli_*` should be used whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in while loop

Add the selected option name or value in if condtion loop and define a vaiable there

```
$selectedval = $f3['teenus'];
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$selectedval = '';
while ($f3=mysql_fetch_assoc($q3)) { 
      $klient=$f3['klient']; 
      if ($f3['id']==$klient) { $selected = "selected"; $selectedval .= $f3['teenus'];  }  //add it here
      echo '<option value="'.$f3['id'].'" $selected>'.$f3['vnimi'].'-'.$f3['teenus'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
```

Add this variable in place holder

```
<input type="text" name="kogus" placeholder="<?php echo $selectedval ;  ?>">
```